# How to list imported functions (.plt) for an ELF executable without disassembling using objdump?

Tags: linux, elf, symbol-table

Currently, I check for imported functions (`.plt`) using `objdump`:

```
objdump -D -j .plt myprog | grep '@plt'
```

However, it doesn't seem right to have `objdump` output annotated disassembly to `grep` to list imported (`.plt`) functions.

To check exported functions, I use `readelf -s myprog`, but the imported `.plt` functions doesn't show up here?

How can I list all imported (`.plt`) function in an ELF executable?

Comment: `nm -D your_prog | grep -w U`

Comment: Thanks @mosvy - why do `.plt` symbols correspond to `"U" The symbol is undefined`? Is it because, it is first resolved at runtime using dynamic linking? Also, could `.plt` symbols be output by `readelf`?

Comment: 1. `nm -D` is more general than ELF and will tell you about all dynamic symbols; the undefined ones from an executable are of course those that should be resolved at run time. 2. I don't know about `readelf` -- please post a reproducible testcase instead of some vague claims. In any case, your `objdump | grep plt` thing will display `__libc_start_main@` as `printf@plt+..` with a stripped binary, so it's completely useless. 3. the binutils tools make it unnecessarily hard to rev-eng stripped binaries -- every time I had the need, I had to put up my own thing, instead of fighting with them.

Comment: @mosvy - thanks, just curiousity: What did you use instead of binutils for stripped binaries? Something you coded yourself? Also, for a stripped binary, all symbols will be lost, so there won't be any `__libc_start_main@`, neither `printf@plt`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Objdump is okay for your intended purpose. To list all the contents of the.plt section of the ELF, you can use the following command:

```
objdump -d --full-contents --section=.plt <elf_file_name>
```